# Can not close the modal second time after its revealed using Zurb Foundation5

Tags: jquery, ajax, zurb-foundation-5, zurb-reveal

I am using ajax call to reveal my modal and then closing it using any of the following three ways:

1. By clicking on background div
2. By pressing `esc` key
3. By clicking on the close button (`X`)

And it is working absolutely fine for all three options
But when it is `opened -> closed -> opened` again its not closing by any of the ways it is expected to be closed.

Here is my html code:

```
<div class="reveal-modal-bg" style="display: block;">
</div>
<div id="trigger-reveal-size-match" class="reveal-modal small open" data-    reveal="" style="display: block; opacity: 1; visibility: visible; top:   50px;">
 <!--
    Couple of divs here
 -->
   <a class="close-reveal-modal cc-icon-x" data-reveal-id="trigger-reveal-size-match"></a>
</div>
```

and here is my JS code:

```
$(".close-reveal-modal").on("click touchend", function() {
    var revealId = "#" + $(this).attr("data-reveal-id");
    $(revealId).foundation('reveal', 'close');
});
```

Anyone out there who knows how to fix this issue please help.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I did not heard about Zurb Foundation till now.....still as I see on the web it's  front end framework..... what you can see on the console when it did not work?

Comment: Can you take download latest js from  Zurb Foundation5 and try again. It seems it was a  code fix from another defect that might have caused this problem.

Comment: @Akki619 there is nothing on the console.I'll try latest js from Zurb Foundation5 and let you know.